# Last substring of string

Tags: java, string

In Java we have `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf`. Is there anything like `lastSubstring`? It  should work like :

```
"aaple".lastSubstring(0, 1) = "e";
```

Comment: Err, what do `0` and `1` represent? And do you mean that `e` is returned?

Comment: `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` both take a string and find it without the main string, returning the location. You seem to be describing the opposite; you want a version of `substring()` that counts from the end instead of the beginning

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not in the standard Java API, but ...

Apache Commons has a lot of handy String helper methods in StringUtils

... including 
StringUtils.right("apple",1)

http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#right(java.lang.String,%20int)

just grab a copy of commons-lang.jar from commons.apache.org

Comment: Great find. Who wrote commons-lang?

Comment: Dead link.  That's why SO generally frowns on answers that are just links.

Answer (score 4):

Generalizing the other responses, you can implement lastSubstring as follows:

```
s.substring(s.length()-endIndex,s.length()-beginIndex);
```

Comment: A nice thing of this implementation is that it runs in O(1) time.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps [lasIndexOf(String)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29) ?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that just be

```
String string = "aaple";
string.subString(string.length() - 1, string.length());
```

?

Comment: Wouldn't that just be `string.subString(string.length() - 1);` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.length() and String.length() - 1

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to get a substring after some ending delimiter, e.g. parsing `file.txt` out of `/some/directory/structure/file.txt`

I found this helpful: [StringUtils.substringAfterLast](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringAfterLast%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
public static String substringAfterLast(String str,
                                        String separator)
Gets the substring after the last occurrence of a separator. The separator is not returned.
A null string input will return null. An empty ("") string input will return the empty string. An empty or null separator will return the empty string if the input string is not null.
If nothing is found, the empty string is returned.
       StringUtils.substringAfterLast(null, *)      = null
       StringUtils.substringAfterLast("", *)        = ""
       StringUtils.substringAfterLast(*, "")        = ""
       StringUtils.substringAfterLast(*, null)      = ""
       StringUtils.substringAfterLast("abc", "a")   = "bc"
       StringUtils.substringAfterLast("abcba", "b") = "a"
       StringUtils.substringAfterLast("abc", "c")   = ""
       StringUtils.substringAfterLast("a", "a")     = ""
       StringUtils.substringAfterLast("a", "z")     = ""
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not aware of that sort of counterpart to `substring()`, but it's not really necessary. You can't efficiently find the last index with a given value using `indexOf()`, so `lastIndexOf()` is necessary. To get what you're trying to do with `lastSubstring()`, you can efficiently use `substring()`.

```
String str = "aaple";
str.substring(str.length() - 2, str.length() - 1).equals("e");
```

So, there's not really any need for `lastSubstring()`.

Comment: `s.substring(...) == "e"` **always** returns false!

Comment: Well, not *always* (the JVM can reuse strings, but it doesn't have to), but you're right. That's not the correct way to do it - I haven't been using enough Java lately...

Comment: Yes, always (at least for all JVM's I ever used). `substring(...)` creates a new string so `==` will always return false. Only String literals inside .java files are pooled and re-used. The boolean x for the snippet `String a = "foo"; String b = "foo"; boolean x = a == b;` will be `true`.

Comment: It's implementation-dependent and can vary from JVM to JVM, so you should *not* count on it, but it *can* happen. However, since it's an optimization, it's only likely to happen when doing so would likely have a performance benefit. And in this case, it's an unlikely optimization since it would be inefficient to always check new strings against existing ones, which is why it's unlikely to ever be true in this case. So, it's not surprising that you've never seen it in this sort of situation. String literals are a much more straightforward optimization, hence why they happen.

Comment: Jonathan, did you miss my remark *'at least for all JVM's I ever used'* ? And "Performance benefit"? "since it's an optimization"? Huh?

Comment: Yes I did see that part. Maybe I just wasn't clear enough. In any case, the only reason for a particular optimization is if it is actually a performance benefit (one type of optimization *can* hurt performance in other ways after all). My point was that the reason that you haven't seen this situation share string instances in any JVM that you've used is likely because optimizing the memory in that way would cost too much in terms of execution efficiency. So, the optimization would likely actually hurt performance rather than benefit it.

Comment: @Bart K - "for all JVM's I ever used" does not mean "always", let alone **"always"**.  There are sure to be JVMs that you have never used, and some of them do not (did not) use one single line of Sun code.

Comment: @Stephen C, sure, that's why I specifically mentioned that fact in my second comment.

Comment: @Bart K - I know, I know, but it is *such fun* watching you try to avoid admitting that you were **wrong** :-)

Comment: @Stephen C, I give up, I give up! I admit I was **wrong** ! ... <mumble>sadist</mumble> :)